# How to add column for a view in Hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I created view `myview` with two columns `ID` and `Name`. But I want add extra column for this.

I using the query as :

```
ALTER VIEW myview ADD COLUMNS (AGE int);
```

But I am getting error as:

> required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'columns' in add
>   partition statement.

Any help me in this?

Comment: ALTER VIEW myview
As

Select ID ,Name,Newcolumn from table_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to get the new column from the table from which the view was created.

```
alter view myview as select col_1 ,col_2 ,Age from your_table
```